# How to place multiple sub figures in the same position, width and height in beamer?

Tags: beamer, subfloats, itemize, columns

I have spend all day and still can not figure it how to do it. This question is related with [How to place multiple TikZ figures in the same position/height in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226132/how-to-place-multiple-tikz-figures-in-the-same-possition-height-in-beamer) I have tried all possible solutions but I can not find the solution to my problem. I end up always all my figures to be moved down outside of the slide. I used in several positions `\vspace{-2cm}` with different size but at the end the result was still not satisfying. There must be an easier way of doing this.

Does anybody have any idea how to improve my output?

Thank you in advance for your time and effort reading and replying to my question.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}%Makes the text appear before it presents nice!!!! 
    \begin{columns}[t] % contents are top vertically aligned
      \begin{column}[T]{5cm} % each column can also be its own environment
        \begin{itemize}
            \item \invisible<2-4>{Item 1}
            \item \invisible<3-4>{Item 2}
            \item \invisible<4-4>{Item 3}
            \item Item 4
          \end{itemize}  
      \end{column}
    \begin{column}[T]{5cm} % alternative top-align that's better for graphics
      \begin{figure}
        \visible<1-1>{%
          \begin{subfigure}[b]{1.0\linewidth}
            \caption{Subcaption 1} \label{fig:subcap1}\hfill
            \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{www}
          \end{subfigure}\hfill
        }%
        \visible<2-2>{%
          \begin{subfigure}[b]{1.0\linewidth}
            \caption{Subcaption 2} \label{fig:subcap2}\hfill
            \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{www}
          \end{subfigure}
        }%
        \visible<3-3>{%
          \begin{subfigure}[b]{1.0\linewidth}
            \caption{Subcaption 3} \label{fig:subcap3}\hfill
            \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{www}
          \end{subfigure}
        }%
        \visible<4-4>{%
          \begin{subfigure}[b]{1.0\linewidth}
            \caption{Subcaption 4} \label{fig:subcap4}\hfill
            \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{www}
          \end{subfigure}
        }%
      \captionsetup{justification=centering} %Center a two line caption
      \caption{Final Caption} \label{fig:largeFigure}
      \end{figure}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The remark is that it is not good to use `caption` and `subcaption` packages in beamer as they are not compatible fully (I removed them). You have also used `[b]` in your `subfigure` hence every thing is bottom aligned. It is better to use the `width` instead of `scale` in `\includegraphics`

Here is your modified code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}%Makes the text appear before it presents nice!!!!
    \begin{columns}[T] % contents are top vertically aligned
      \begin{column}{5cm} % each column can also be its own environment
        \begin{itemize}
            \item \invisible<2-4>{Item 1}
            \item \invisible<3-4>{Item 2}
            \item \invisible<4-4>{Item 3}
            \item Item 4
          \end{itemize}
      \end{column}
    \begin{column}{5cm} % alternative top-align that's better for graphics
      \begin{figure}
        \only<1>{%
           \centering Subcaption 1
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
        }%
        \only<2>{%
          \centering Subcaption 2
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-b}
        }%
        \only<3>{%
          \centering Subcaption 3
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-c}
        }%
        \only<4>{%
          \centering Subcaption 4
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image}
        }%
      \caption{Final Caption} \label{fig:largeFigure}
      \end{figure}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Harish Kumar for your time and effort, the solution looks perfect apart from one minor comment. I was hoping that I would be able to use ´\visible{}´ so I could also the the sub figure enumeration. I will try to make it work and I will post my answer here in case someone might need that after. Again thank you for your time and effort to assist me with my problem.

Comment: @Thanos sure, but remember that`\visible<3>` is enough instead of `\visible<3-3>`

Comment: Thank you for the hint @Harish Kumar. I tried any possible modification but I end up in the same problem. I need to go manually and modify the `\vspace{}` and `\hspace{}` so I can bring the figure to the correct position. I assume that the `\visible{}` is producing white space which makes after the first sub figure. So I got stack again, unless I forget about the possibility of having sub figure enumeration.